# JOIN on column that may contain NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    Users.id,
    Countries.name 
FROM
    Users, Countries
WHERE 
    Users.country_id = Countries.id
```

The issue is that `Users.country_id` can sometimes be `NULL`, and if it is the entire row is not returned.  I want it to return the row but with 'null' or '' in that column.  I tried this:

```
SELECT
    Users.id,
    Countries.name 
FROM
    Users, Countries
WHERE 
    (Users.country_id = Countries.id OR Users.country_id IS NULL)
```

However that returns the row once ***for each*** **`Countries.id`** ***that exists***.  How do I work around this?

Comment: You can use Outer Joins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  users.id, countries.name
FROM    users
LEFT JOIN
        countries
ON      countries.id = users.country_id
```

This is a good example of why the `ANSI` join syntax (using the `JOIN` keyword) is preferred.

Comment: Thank you.  This works.  Out of curiosity I also tried the 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' and it works too.

Comment: @alnafie: `OUTER` is pure syntactic sugar.

Comment: that means `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the same thing as `LEFT JOIN` (syntactic sugar, haha)

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is *unrefined* syntactic sugar ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT          Users.id,
                Countries.name
FROM            Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN Countries ON Users.country_id = Countries.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Users.id,
    Countries.name 
FROM
    Users, Countries
WHERE 
    Users.country_id = Countries.id
UNION
SELECT
    id,
    '{{no country}}' AS name 
FROM
    Users
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                  FROM Countries
                 WHERE Users.country_id = Countries.id );
```

Comment: `UNION` will do unnecesary work to eliminate duplicates. UNION ALL should be used. However, The entire query is unncessary, there exists OUTER JOINS and mysql supports it.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: "The entire query is unncessary[sic]" -- You seem to be implying that using `OUTER JOIN` is necessary: care to prove it? `OUTER JOIN` is a kind of union anyhow, one expressly designed to generate nulls and I prefer to avoid nulls.